# how to fix undefined method errors in Laravel 7.x phpunit?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-7

I am experiencing strange errors. Like all of the common functions I saw online does are undefined in my phpunit..

I ran the test like this

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

my code is like this

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
    
    
    class AppTest extends TestCase
    {
    
    
        use DatabaseMigrations;
        use WithoutMiddleware;
    
    
        /** @test */
        public function test_can_push_data() {
    
            $paramData = [
                'param1' => 'value1',
                'param2' => 'value2',
    
            ];
    
            $response = $this->json('POST', route('app.push'), $paramData);
    
            $response->assertStatus(200);
        }
    
    }
```

I am getting this error

```
1) Tests\Unit\AppTest::test_can_push_data
Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Unit\AppTest::json()
```

I also noticed that am getting errors for other functions, I don't know why

```
$this->post()
$this->get()
```

Any ideas what's going on?, most of the tutorials I saw online are using these common methods, and these are throwing errors in my code ..why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extending the wrong `TestCase` class. PHPUnit's TestCase class does not have those methods. You are looking for the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` class. This will allow your tests to use the methods per the documentation:

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
    
    
    class AppTest extends TestCase
    ...
```

It is worth noting, that it is ususally useful to create your own `TestCase` class, to provide common custom functionality. It is usually located at `Tests\TestCase`

Comment: Yes i solved the issue yesterday after days of crawling google..its so weird why laravel chose to extend thar way by dedault